# How to convert 4D numpy array to 2D by fixing indices

Tags: numpy

I have a 4D numpy array `A` of shape `(N,N,N,N)` that I would like to convert to a 2D matrix `M` of shape `(N,N)` by fixing pairs of indices. For example

```
M[i,j] = A[i,j,i,j]
```

How should this be done in numpy, avoiding for loops?

Edit:
I will subsequently access the elements of `M` using an index array provided by `numpy.ix_` so accessing elements of the 4D array in analoguous way would be a solution as well.

Comment: How about `numpy.reshape` (see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

Comment: Sounds like a kind of diagonal, a subset of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a workaround:

```py
i, j = np.arange(N), np.arange(N)
j_idx, i_idx = np.meshgrid(i, j)
M = A[i_idx, j_idx, i_idx, j_idx]
```

Uses [meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to generate the indexing pattern beforehand and then [fancy indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) the array `A` to get `M`. As @hpaulj suggested, you can specify `sparse = True` in `np.meshgrid()` to obtain broadcastable *1D* arrays instead of full *2D* index arrays to save some space.

You can also do this using `np.ix_()` as well:

```py
ixgrid = np.ix_(i, j)
M = A[ixgrid + ixgrid]
```

Since `ixgrid` is a 2-tuple, `ixgrid + ixgrid` produces the 4-tuple required for indexing `A`.

Comment: I think you could specify `sparse` in `meshgrid`.